# Deciding transitivity of a directed acyclic graph

Tags: time-complexity, directed-acyclic-graph, upper-bounds, boolean-matrix

Is there any algorithm that decides whether a given directed acyclic graph is transitive or not, in time-complexity asymptotically better than boolean matrix multiplication?

Comment: By virgi's answer to your other [question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21470/transitivity-check-vs-transitive-clousure) it's probably worths to merge this with the previous one.